# Is there an apex function that replicates the Describe Layouts Rest Api call

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have a requirement that needs me to describe a layout on an apex controller, currently I found this Rest Api method that suits my needs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_layouts.htm

Is there an apex equivalent method?

And if not how can I call that Api from my apex class, bear in mind that these needs to run in a scheduled method where there is no sessionId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the details via [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm). And in Summer 17 Salesforce released [Apex Metadata API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_metadata_api/units/apex_metadata_api_intro). So you can access metadata from your Apex code to access Page layouts.

Example code snippet:

```
List<String> accLayoutNameList = new List<String>{'Account-Account Layout', 'Account-Account (Sales) Layout'};
List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, accLayoutNameList);

Metadata.Layout accLayout = (Metadata.Layout) components.get(0);
```