# How to get compactLayouts through apex Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata, compact-layout

I am trying to get compact layouts using metatadataapi. I am using https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls this repo to get Compact Layouts.

I have written a following code to get compact layout.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort metadata = MetadataService.createService();
MetadataService.CompactLayout cl = (MetadataService.CompactLayout) metadata.readMetadata('CompactLayout', new String[] { 'Contact-APINameForCompactLayout' }).getRecords()[0];
system.debug(cl);
```

But in response I am getting following response

```
CompactLayout:[Metadata.fullName=null, apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field_order_type_info=(fullName, fields, label), fields=null, fields_type_info=(fields, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), fullName=null, fullName_type_info=(fullName, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), label=null, label_type_info=(label, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 1, 1, false), type=CompactLayout, type_att_info=(xsi:type)]
```

I have tried different name combination for in

> new String[] { 'Contact-APINameForCompactLayout' }

I have tried

- ObjectName-APINameForCompactLayout
- ObjectName.APINameForCompactLayout
- ObjectName.LabelForCompactLayout
- ObjectName-LabelForCompactLayout
- ObjectName-recordTypeName
- ObjectName.recordTypeName

But nothing in working.

I also looked into metadata namespace that works for apex natively for metadata operations. [Is there an apex function that replicates the Describe Layouts Rest Api call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207828/is-there-an-apex-function-that-replicates-the-describe-layouts-rest-api-call)
But it only works for Layouts not compactLayouts.

What am I missing here?How I can get compactLayouts using Metadata API?

Comment: Have you tried just passing in "ObjectName"?

Comment: yes I have tried that also

Answer (score 0):

For CompactLayout fullName is ObjectApiName.CompactLayoutApiName. When I try below code it returns the correct response.

```
MetadataService.CompactLayout cl = (MetadataService.CompactLayout) metadata.readMetadata('CompactLayout', new String[] { 'Contact.QuickStartLayout' }).getRecords()[0];
```

And response is:

```
23:08:20:441 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|CompactLayout:[Metadata.fullName=null, apex_schema_type_info=(http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, true, false), field_order_type_info=(fullName, fields, label), fields=(Name, Title, AccountId, Phone, MobilePhone, Email, OwnerId), fields_type_info=(fields, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, -1, false), fullName=Contact.QuickStartLayout, fullName_type_info=(fullName, http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata, null, 0, 1, false), label=Quick Start Layout, label_type_info=(label, htt
```

You can check and verify the correcy fullName from [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com) by going to `Info -> Metadata Types & Components` and then selecting CompactLayout. Under Components you can see your CompactLayout's information.